# Broken transformation matrices in C# Assimp import of DirectX model file?

Tags: c#, opengl, directx, models, assimp

I want to use the DirectX model format in my OpenGL engine. I use Assimp to import the model files.
I would like to use DirectX because the Assimp importer recognizes the different animations pretty well. If I have multiple animations in my Collada file (exported with the "Better Collada Exporter" for Blender), Assimp only recognizes one animation.

But, I have a strange problem concerning the import of DirectX model files. A video may describe it better...

This is how it looks when I export my blender file to Collada and import it via Assimp (correctly rendered):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jvilcem4g7vjgdp/animation_collada.mp4?dl=0

This is the same blender file exported to DirectX model in my engine:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3u6g9qmzuje5aap/animation_directx.mp4?dl=0

Somehow, I think the transformation matrices in the animation channels seem to be a bit off. It looks like they are rotated the wrong way (or on the wrong axis?)

Do you have any experience with this? I tried loading the DirectX file into open3mod model viewer, and it renders the animations perfectly.

Maybe there is some import config flag that I forgot to set?
Maybe my Blender export settings are wrong? I export with:

- Right Handed
- Y-Up

Cheers and thanks for your help.

Comment: The transformation matrices are different between D3D and OpenGL I'm pretty sure. Specifically the projection matrix. And it's not clear exactly what you'd have to change because it's a long mess from eye space, projection matrix, clip space, NDC and so on. I think the best thing to do would be to into Blender and create a reference model with orthogonal pointers showing X, Y, Z axes clearly marked and visible. Export it, import it, draw it in your engine and see where it's wrong. Stuff like this is always messy, you may even have wrong triangle winding order and inverted normals or the like.

Comment: @Zebrafish thank you for your comment. I would do that, but since the Assimp model viewer renders my model just fine, I would think that the exported model is okay. I guess it is the way that I import it in my engine. I do not set any specific flags when importing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found a solution:

Assimp needs a true DirectX model file (left-handed, y-up), so my export settings in Blender are now:
[Link to Blender DirectX export settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTLm9.jpg)

And in my import method (c#) I do:

```
if(modelfile.ToLower().EndsWith(".x"))
{
    model = importer.ImportFile(modelfile, PostProcessSteps.LimitBoneWeights
                    | PostProcessSteps.Triangulate
                    | PostProcessSteps.ValidateDataStructure
                    | PostProcessSteps.FlipWindingOrder
                    | PostProcessSteps.FixInFacingNormals
            );
}
else
{
    model = importer.ImportFile(modelfile, PostProcessSteps.LimitBoneWeights
                    | PostProcessSteps.Triangulate
                    | PostProcessSteps.ValidateDataStructure
            );
}
```

Works flawlessly. Thanks to Zebrafish for pointing me in the right direction.